# Why upload_max_filesize not increase even it set correctly in php.ini?

Tags: file-upload, cpanel, filesize

I would like to upload 1G file to public_html dir of cpanel.
So I set post_max_size = 2048M and upload_max_filesize=2048M inside php.ini.

[image]

But it didn't set correctly and it suspend when uploading filesize over than 150M.

So what am I getting wrong?
Any help, tips will be great help for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

either there must be a seperate php.ini file located in public_html which has the value of 150MB ( if you are using suphp ) and hence its not showing the updated values. You have to check it first.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you will have to ask you provider to do.

If your the owner of the server and can login to WHM it's under:

> Tweak Settings => PHP Settings => Maximum Upload Size

Newer version have it listed under:

> Home => Service Configuration => PHP Configuration Editor => Tweak
>   Settings => PHP